# Need to get rid of disk image after Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, disk-image

[image]

So, I was using Bootcamp, but during the point where it asked me to create the partition size, I decided that I no longer wanted to do it anymore and I used the quit option. However, after quitting Boot Camp, it left me with those two disk images and I don't know how to get rid of them. The erase option in disc utility would give me an error. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Quit Disk Utility. View the disk images in the Finder. Grab them with the cursor, and drag them to the Trash. Empty the Trash.

Comment: I tried that. Problem is, those disk images don’t show up in Finder.  Is there some command I can use or something?

Comment: .dmg are files; they're somewhere on your Mac. Search for them. Downloads folder? Applications folder?